# Overclocked pi too much

Tags: overclocking

Out of curiosity, I overclocked my pi to turbo. However, now when I start the pi, it freezes at the splash screen and refuses to boot. I am using the RetroPie OS. Is there anything that I can do in order to change the overclock setting so that I can boot the pi again? Would it be possible to read the SD card into my main computer and change the overclock settings?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it would.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md

> The various system configuration parameters, which would traditionally be edited and stored using a BIOS, **are stored in an optional text file named config.txt**. This is read by the GPU before the ARM CPU (and Linux) is initialised; therefore it must be located on the first (boot) partition of your SD card, alongside bootcode.bin and start.elf. This file is normally accessible as /boot/config.txt from Linux and must be edited as root; but **from Windows or OS X it is seen as a file in the only accessible part of the card**.

Comment: Note that neither this answer or the quoted text address that fact that due to the way Windows and Linux uses different characters to indicate a new line, that simply using Notepad on Windows and then saving the file will render the file unreadable by the kernel. You should use something like Notepad++ that preserves the correct file ending characters.